# Crontab is using some sort of hidden cache?

Tags: linux, php, cron, crontab

I used to have a crontab that ran like this

`* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/agent/time_keeper.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

It worked fine. Now I moved that php script to a new directory and I now have the cron run like this

`* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/agent/php/time_keeper.php > /dev/null 2>&1`

The new cron does not work. The file is there. I can run it fine from my browser. When I move the file back to its first directory and use the old cron, it works.

What is going on here?

Comment: are you getting some sort of error?

Comment: did you use `crontab -e`  to edit the crontab?

Comment: What happens if you run the exact same command `/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/agent/php/time_keeper.php` from the console (and not from the browser)?

Comment: It is possible that your PHP file `time_keeper` is failing due to an include etc??  Have you looked at your logs?

Comment: I used `crontab -e`. When I execute the script from shell it works correctly. The time_keeper script works fine. I am getting no errors.

Comment: Are the ownership or permissions on the the new file or directory different from the original?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to install your crontab - assuming you saved that line in a file called myfile.conf:

```
$ crontab myfile.conf
```

Note that this will overwrite all existing crontab entries.

Comment: I don't understand. What am I doing here?

Comment: Crontab basically has a 'file' containing the jobs it has to run at which interval, for each user. You can update it by installing it (as above) or by editing the version crontab is running (by the -e flag).

Following the comment thread above - do you have the crontab running under a different user? If so, crontab is still running the old command under a different user, and you've put a new task for it with the updated command under your user.